# How to return current date and time from called activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having a hard time figuring out how to return the current date and time string from the called activity to the calling activity in the setResult statement.  From what I have been able to research, it seem to involve creating a Bundle object with putExtras method.  Do I use putString method for the string data?  It needs a key and a value.  Would appreciate some example code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
Uri data = Uri.parse("content://anything/");
Intent result = new Intent(null,data);
result.putExtra("DATE",dateVariable);
setResult(RESULT_OK,result);
finish();
```

and for reading override `onActivityResult`...

call `data.getData()` to get the Uri...
call `data.getStringExtra("DATE")` to get the date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setResult(RESULT_OK,intent).

intent means the Intent including data you want.

you can put some extras to the intent and pass it by setResult.

search for some sample codes.

Answer (score 0):

In the activity from where you will get the date : Write below code:

Intent intent = new Intent(nameoftheactivitywhereyourpresent.**this**,nameoftheactivitywhereyouwantpassthedate.**class**);

intent.putExtra("Date",date);
startActivity(intent);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

In the activity where you want to retrieve the date write below code.

Intent getIntent = getIntent();
String retailercodeCollection  = getIntent.getStringExtra("Date");

Comment: Thanks to your answers.  Before I saw your answers, to my surprise I was able to return the data using the following snippet of code after learning from an example about returning a string:

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("1st_String",strDate);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();

But I will learn from your answers other ways to achieve the same result!